# eclipse IDE crashes after seconds with JVM terminated. Exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse IDE Galileo fine on Ubuntu 10.04.(with JRE in the eclipse root directory)
When I tried to download and use new eclipse HELIOS it crashes instantly or after 10 seconds maximum with this error message

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /home/arefaey/devel/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/arefaey/devel/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/arefaey/devel/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.0.v20100503/eclipse_1307.so
-startup /home/arefaey/devel/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-exitdata 1758045
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /home/arefaey/devel/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
```

I googled and tried many suugestions :

- Changed the eclipse directory
- Changed the workspace directory
- changed the eclipse.ini -Xmx256 to 512 or higher
- Deleted the eclipse.ini file.
- Copied the JRE directory -which works with Galileo- to the HELIOS root directory

It woud be great if I got help with that as HELIOS is really faster.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Anything in /path/to/workspace/.metadata/.log? Which Java version?

Comment: Is /usr/bin/java a 32- or 64-bit JVM? Your Eclipse will only work with a 64-bit JVM (see the `--launcher.library` option).

Comment: java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed OpenJDK and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug when using Helios with Java 6u21 on windows, apparently sun changed the name of one of the parameters or something .

There was a discussion a while back on the eclipse forums about adding a message to the main download screen, but apparently they didn't do it.

[Newsgroup link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&goto=545806&)

also

[Link to the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514)

Comment: IIRC, Eclipse has a piece of code which automatically bumps the MaxPermSize parameter when running on the Sun JVM. Oracle then changed the value of the JRE vendor field, causing Eclipse to no longer recognize the JVM as Sun's, and thus not set the MaxPermSize parameter.

Comment: @JesperE: correct, all details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Answer (score 1):

Which JVM do you invoke with?  Eclipse Helios works well with the Sun JVM under Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

There's known issue with Helios and Java 1.6.0_21. wiki.eclipse has a solution (workaround) already.

In brief, either:

- Switch back to 1.6.0_20
- increase perm gen space to 256 MB
- download and use a patched dll.

[Here's the link to the wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Oracle.2FSun_VM_1.6.0_21_on_Windows)

Comment: Modified eclipse.ini -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue running ubuntu 10.04 64 bit:

but I am not using 21.

:/opt$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using eclipse helios, realized running with following args solved my problem
(default vm was 1.6.0_20-b02)

./eclipse\ helios vm /opt2/bea/jdk160_05/bin/java -vmargs -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xms128m -Xmx512m

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are trying to install the 32 bit eclipse on 64 bit OS or vice versa.Try t have the same bit OS as well as Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I know some people has had the same issue with Eclipse using x86_64 versions of Ubuntu and the JVM.

There is a workaround [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514)

Answer (score 0):

well in my case I was in a directory that was deleted, I got the below error as well in the terminal

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1069)
```